# Centering Google reCaptcha (v2) after scaling size with -webkit-transform

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design, recaptcha

I'm building a website for a client in Wordpress.

I need a reCaptcha (v2 API) that is visible on even the smallest of screens.

The height of the compact size is simply too big so I have to stick to using the normal one.

I found a way to center it, by adding these lines to the CSS:

```
.recap1{  
margin: 0px auto !important;
width: auto !important;
height: auto !important;
text-align: -webkit-center;
text-align: -moz-center;
text-align: -o-center;
text-align: -ms-center;
}
```

This centers it, but on the smallest of resolutions, the normal size reCaptcha is too big to fit the form.

So I scaled down the size using -webkit-transform by adding these lines to CSS

```
transform:scale(0.65);
-webkit-transform:scale(0.65);
transform-origin:left top;
-webkit-transform-origin:left top;
```

Right now my CSS for the reCaptcha looks like this:

```
.recap1 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    text-align: -moz-center;
    text-align: -o-center;
    text-align: -ms-center;
    transform:scale(0.65);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.65);
    transform-origin:left top;
    -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
}
```

My issue is that after adding the transformation, it is no longer centered.

It looks like this:
[Screenshot - Small Size for mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCFKW.jpg)
[Screenshot - Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX8MH.jpg)

I was planning to add a transition effect as well.

My question is: How can I scale it down AND make it centered at the same time?

Comment: A picture is nice, but a codepen would be better. You give us a few blocks of code but it is likely that we may need more information. If you can't reproduce the issue in codepen/jsfiddle or link to the site, I'm not sure how much help you're going to get.

Comment: Here it is in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rvR303/278o7bvo/

Comment: It I change

transform-origin:left top;
-webkit-transform-origin:left top;

to center, then it's centered, but causes resonsiveness problems on smaller screens.